# replace file Errror: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

im an beginner in python. I dont understand the Error. Please can you help me?

```
import fileinput

ersetzendic = {
"abc":"TESTabc",
"ABC":"TESTABC",
"qwertz":"TESTqwertz",
"wtf":"TESTwtf",
"wtfee":"TESTwtf2"
}


for line in fileinput.input("readme.txt", inplace=True):
    for sonicsyntax in ersetzendic:
        ersetzendic = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]
        line = line.replace(sonicsyntax,ersetzendic)
    print(line, end="" )
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What are you trying to? Please explain.

Comment: i want to replace text in txt. file

Comment: in my dic the key is the searching text if it match/exist in the readme.txt file it should be replace with the value from my dic. example in readme.txt file exist "abc" the code should replace it to "TESTabc"

Comment: How does your text file look like? I am sure you can do this without the `fileinput` module

Comment: in my readme.txt file there is just the key strings from my dic: abc
ABC
qwertz
wtf
wtfee

Comment: Do you only want to use fileinput

Comment: no. do u have a solution? it should replace the keys with the value, but not the entire file. if there are words they dont match it should stay that way

Comment: Yes it is possible!

Comment: how? I can’t get any further. trying since 2h

Comment: So you want to get the lines of a file that match with dict and change the words with the values of dicts right?

Comment: yes right. example: i have 100 Bucks in my Pocket.  dic = { "bucks" : "shoes", "pocket": "cabinet" } i have 100 shoes in my cabinet. this should be happen in a file

Answer (score 0):

when you write `ersetzendic = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]` you are trying to access an `str` by a value that is not an `int`.

By the looks of it may be a tuple of `(key, value)` from your dict `ersetzendic`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is (unnecessarily) overwriting the variable: `ersetzendic` in the line:

```
ersetzendic = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]
```

so instead of an array of strings it turns into a string on the first iteration, and in the second iteration we're trying to access an index of that string using a string as a key - which is why it fails.

We can modify the last 3 lines from:

```
for sonicsyntax in ersetzendic:
    ersetzendic = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]
    line = line.replace(sonicsyntax,ersetzendic)
```

to:

```
for sonicsyntax in ersetzendic: 
    line = line.replace(sonicsyntax, ersetzendic[sonicsyntax])
```

Comment: @point the answer was updated to suggest a fix as well, I hope that it clarifies the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to replace the words in a file which contains any of the keys in `ersetzendic` with their corresponding value in the dict. In your solution, the produced error was occurred due to this segment:

```
for sonicsyntax in ersetzendic:
    ersetzendic = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]
```

With this, in the first iteration, you took a key from `ersetzendic` and reassigned `ersetzendic` taking the corresponding value of it. So that `ersetzendic` is now overwritten with a String value, that is not a dict anymore.

So, in the next iteration, when you're trying to repeat the thing, as `ersetzendic` is a string, accessing `ersetzendic[something]` is nothing but trying to accessing a character of specific index. Hence you're getting the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However, you can take each line from the file, then each key of the dict `ersetzendic` and do a simple `line.replace(target, replacingString)` for your job. So, you can change the implementation as below:

```
for line in fileinput.input("readme.txt", inplace=True):
    for key in ersetzendic:
        line = line.replace(key,ersetzendic[key])
    print(line, end="" )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is cause of the line `line = line.replace(sonicsyntax,ersetzendic)` here `ersetzendic` is a string value which is one of the values stored in the dictionary cause of the line `ersetzendic = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]` which changes your dictionary `ersetzendic` to a string.
And you can not use `str` values to access strings.

I read in the comments about what you want to do.
Here is how to fix it:

```py
import fileinput

ersetzendic = {
"abc":"TESTabc",
"ABC":"TESTABC",
"qwertz":"TESTqwertz",
"wtf":"TESTwtf",
"wtfee":"TESTwtf2"
}

with fileinput.input(files=("readme.txt",), inplace=True) as input:    # using the context manager is a better way to read lines using the FileInput object
    for line in input:
        for sonicsyntax in ersetzendic:
            replacement_text = ersetzendic[sonicsyntax]    # store the value of the text to be reolaced in a new variable
            line = line.replace(sonicsyntax,replacement_text)    # pass the key as the first argument and the replacement text as the second
        print(line,end='')
```

This is what `readme.txt` looks like before the execution of the code:

```
abc
ABEABC
wtfrrrrrwtf
wtfgwtfee
qwertyqweertz
```

This is the file content after the code is executed:

```
TESTabc
ABETESTABC
TESTwtfrrrrrTESTwtf
TESTwtfgTESTTESTwtf2
qwertyqweertz
```

Comment: This is my solution based on my inference of your question,let me know if this works as per your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

`item` is most likely a string in your code; the string indices are the ones in the square brackets. So I'd first check your `data` variable to see what you received there; I guess that data is a list of strings (or at least a list containing at least one string) while it should be a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use `file input` module. Then I have an easy solution. Look at this example -

**txt file**:

```
abc
ABC
qwe
```

**Code**:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f: # Read The file
    lst = f.read().split()
    
for i in ersetzendic: # Replace desired elements
    lst = [ersetzendic[i] if x==i else x for x in lst]

with open('1.txt','w') as f: # Write to file
    for i in lst:
        f.write(i+'\n')
```

**Result in .txt file**:

```
TESTabc
TESTABC
qwe
```

I think you can implement this in your code!